# How to feed the training examples one by one in tensorflow (e.g., cifar example)

Tags: tensorflow

Just want to feed the data according to the original order in tensorflow. Specifically, I am working on the cifar10 example. Do anyone knows how to guarantee that examples are fed exactly the same order as they are in the data file?

Comment: any specific reason you want them in same order ? Cifar example uses tf.train.shuffle_batch(). You could make it not shuffle the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just want to do some provenance to understand the behavior of the network. Different orders would make it hard to do so. I use the shuffle=False for shuffle_batch. However, it seems the order is still not guaranteed. I mean in different epoch, the order of training data is different.

Comment: You might have to put *shuffle = False* in the string input producer too. Like in this one : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L158

Comment: That's what I did, I use shuffle = false for both string input producer and shuflle_batch. I also tried to merge the 5 input batch into one file. It still not working. Seems there is still shuffling somewhere.

Comment: I finally get it done. It seems multiple GPUs makes the order a little complicated. The single GPU solution works.